# Missing events in properties for VB6

Tags: vb6

I am a  self taught amateur Visual  Basic programmer.  My programs are for myself, friends and some non-profit  organizations.  I have a situation that I thought would be reasonably simple but doesn't seems the case.

I have a text box array of 6 elements (1 -6) named "txtBilled" .When the value is entered into any but element 6  I want to add the values in  1-5 and put result in element 6.   My problems start due to the fact that the properties for the text array does  not provide for a lost focus  option.   Searching the inter  provides  statements that  this is normal, others say the "Lost Focus" should always be there.
As a second approach I tried to  use the validate element. Never used this before created  a sub as follows that I found on the web.

```
Private sub  txtBilled__Validate(Cancel as Boolean)
```

Found that the Validate event  is also not included in the properties for the array
I am using VB6 version  8176 under Windows 10.
Any ideal as  to what I am doing incorrectly would be appreciated.

Comment: If `txtBilled` is a control array, there should be an `Index` parameter in its event subs. Have you selected the `_Validate` event from the dropdown list? If so, the supplied prototype should include that parameter... as should the `_LostFocus` event.

Comment: Agree with @JimMack - you should have LostFocus event with Index as a parameter if you've actually created a true Textbox array. If you click on each of the textboxes you should see the array index as part of each control name eg. `txtBilled(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you not create your own LostFocus sub using the Index of the textbox array?

```
Private Sub txtBilled_LostFocus(Index As Integer)
   Dim i As Integer    
   dim sngTotal As Single

   '  Calculate sum only if not in last textbox
   If Index <> uBound(txtBilled) Then
        For i = LBound(txtBilled) to UBound(txtBilled) - 1
            sngTotal = sngTotal + txtBilled(i)
        Next i 
        txtBilled(uBound(txtBilled)) = sngTotal
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There's an error in your example - It's adding all the textboxes. Should be `... To Ubound(txtBilled) -1`

Comment: Good pickup Bill. Thanks